# How to apply two validation in one cell on Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, validation

I have to apply two validation on a range of cell in Excel. The first validation is If A1=inactive, then B2 should populate with N/A, if not, then, (here comes the second validation), the user have to insert number, but it has to be a whole number (second validation).
I tried with an IF function for the first validation and a MOD function for the whole number, and I combined them with AND, also tried with an IF function and nested MOD, but all that worked was the whole number validation.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or how to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: We would need to see the formula you're trying, and the contents of the cells it refers to, to know what might be wrong.  Also, what do you mean by A1=inactive?  Is inactive a literal value or are you referring to something like an empty cell?

Comment: Hi, by inactive I mean this is the value in the cell (text). Here are the formula's that I've tried: =AND(MOD($V2,1)=0,if($U1=”Inactive”,”N/A”,””)
=if($U1=”Inactive, including not in education or training”,”N/A”,MOD($V2,1)=0). Sorry, I didn't actually use column A. So in my column U I have either "Inactive" or  "Unemployed", and I need to populate column V with N/A if the cell in U column is inactive, or have a blank cell where users can enter whole numbers if the client is unemployed (column U)

Comment: OK, you've got some wild and crazy stuff going on there.  It isn't clear what logic you're trying to implement, but that's a long way from Excel syntax (unless you're showing two different formulas, in which case it's only a moderate way from Excel syntax).  Edit the question to add what the values in U1 and V2 can potentially be, and an accurate description of what should happen with those values.  By accurate I mean things like the question refers to `A1=inactive`, but it looks like the formulas are actually `U1="Inactive...other text"`.  (cont'd)

Comment: There are very different ways those need to be handled; you don't want people wasting time developing formulas that won't actually work for you.  Put your formula(s) in the question, where you can format them so people understand what they're looking at.  BTW, AND combines multiple true/false conditions.  The IF test includes a true/false condition, but its result isn't.  So you can't make that part of the AND.   Maybe the AND would be appropriate as the IF test condition, but it isn't clear what logic you're trying to accomplish.  (cont'd)

Comment: The very end of your formula stuff, you have the MOD logical test as the result the IF returns if its condition is false.  I suspect you don't want the output of the IF to be TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: The logic is quite simple, really: if U1 = inactive, then V1 is N/A. If U1=unemployed, then V1 is a number, but has to be a whole number. So I wanted to prevent people from entering decimals...

Comment: So I wanted to combine those two in data validation. I first used A1 as an example, but when you asked for the formulas I had used, I explained that it was actually column U and V I was using. Anyways, thank you for your response

Comment: It's fine if you can reduce this to a simpler requirement that you can adapt, but make the description internally consistent.  The purpose of the site is to create a permanent knowledge base of questions and answers that other people can benefit from.  Comments are transient.  All of the detail defining the question really needs to be edited into the question.  And it needs to be clear and unambiguous enough that not only people who answer can fully understand it, but future readers can understand it and how to adapt it to their situation.  The answers aren't just for you.  :-)

Comment: I see, thank you. I'll have it in mind for next time :)

Comment: Is U1 always either inactive or unemployed, never anything else, including blank?  Where does the user input the value?  Are you referring to V1 and V2 interchangeably?  Are you trying to use the V cell as both a formula result and an input cell?

Comment: @user1064748,, it's not only applying multiple data validation rule but it's like data validation based on adjacent cell's value,, & it needs different approach !!

Comment: @fixer1234,, it's needs a different approach rather than multiple data validation since validation needs to justify adjacent cell's value !!

Comment: @RajeshS, I suspect the OP is using the word generically, and just needs a formula that tests several conditions.  But the question is very ambiguous, and the exact requirements aren't clear.

Comment: @fixer1234,, the OP wants `B2` populate with either `N/A` or whole number (the Integer part),, !!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to populate cell `B2` with **N/A**, if cell `A1` has value `inactive` and cell `B2` must populate with **whole Number** if & when cell `A1` has Number.

To achieve this, different approach is required rather than applying **Data Validation** directly.

**How it works:**

- Enter this Formula in Cell `C1.`

  `=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"",IF(A1="inactive","N/A",INT(A1)))`
- Select Cell `B2` and From *Data Validation's Criteria for **Allow** pick **List***.
- For **Source** enter this `=$C$1`.

[image]

---

[image]

**N.B.**

- As soon you enter data in cell `A1`, either `inactive` or `Number` (*Whole or with Decimal*) or `Blank`, the Formula in `C1` returns
  result accordingly.
- Since cell `B2` reads value from cell `C1`, Excel manages the data as your need along with *Validation* through *Drop down cell/List* method.
- *You may hide Cell `C1`, also adjust cell refrences.*
- *This can be achieved using VBA (Macro) also.*

Comment: Maybe the OP can get some ideas from this if they return, but the question was ambiguous and I'm guessing that this guess at the meaning doesn't reflect the OP's problem.  The ambiguities include (not a complete list): The cell with inactive is different from the cell with the number.  Does it require an exact match to inactive or finding inactive within a text string?  If inactive is there, it gets N/A.  But if it isn't there, does a blank count?  The OP mentioned testing for unemployed in a comment.  Is that the only other possible value or (cont'd)

Comment: does the logic require that the value must be unemployed (and again, is that an exact match or a word contained in a string)?  Where is the number coming from and how does it get there?  Is it a derived or internal number or something the user enters?  A comment implies that it comes from a different cell, but it isn't completely clear that it isn't being entered into the result cell, replacing the formula, and then needing to be dealt with using a different formula.  Assuming it's a different cell, what's the desired action? Truncate and use it?  (cont'd)

Comment: Round and use it? Not accept it and display a message?  Not accept it, display a message, and prevent action from continuing until it's fixed?  Whether it's an internal number or something entered also affects how you might deal with it.  The OP sorta describes the action if every test goes the desired way, but doesn't describe what to do for all of the other combinations of conditions.  The OP doesn't appear interested in clarifying the question; their comment implies that they are abandoning it.  (cont'd)

Comment: I voted to close to avoid a bunch of people wasting time running in wrong directions creating answers to random interpretations.

Comment: @fixer1234, thanks for the observation,,, what OP means to **inactive** is literally not the *inactive cell* but the content of the cell  is text *inactive*,,  I've included *Blank cell* to be tested as extension of the logic test (is in addition),, and the *whole number* is nothing but the *integer* ,, since OP has used `MOD($V2,1)=0)` which justifies the whole number !!

Comment: **Cont,,** the method I've suggested is the only possibility to apply two *Validation through Drop down* (since DD also restricts the data in the cell). Excel doesn't allows to enter other than *N/A*, or *Integer* or *Space*, even directly !!

Comment: The OP is using MOD to test for an integer; I don't think they want to convert input to an integer.  Correct, "inactive" is cell content, but in a comment, the OP shows it as just one word in a sentence.  So it isn't clear whether we can test `="inactive"` or need to test whether FIND locates inactive in a sentence.  You've identified one of many possible interpretations of the question.

Comment: @fixer1234,, OP means whole number as Integer value,, OP's formula `=AND(MOD($V2,1)=0,if($U1=”Inactive”,”N/A”,””) ` simplifies both .

Comment: The OP just performed a test for whether it was a whole number.  The result of the test outputs something else (a blank) in their formula in a comment.  But really, no sense in us arguing about what they want.  Neither of us knows; we can only guess.  That's the reason I voted to close.  :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96445/discussion-between-rajesh-s-and-fixer1234).